# Convert VBA Macro to Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to create a function to retrieve column titles found in row four in an excel sheet. This is what I have so far, can anybody help me please?

```
 Sub Test_Click()
 Dim text As String
 Dim titles(200) As String
 Dim nTitles As Integer

 For i = 1 To 199
    If Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, i).Value) = "" Then
        nTitles = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
    titles(i - 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, i).Value
 Next

 For i = 0 To nTitles
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(20 + i, 1).Value = titles(i)
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: My question is if you can help me to convert this into a function instead of having it as Sub. Thank you

Comment: Functions can't change other cell values.

Comment: @Bmo Yes, they can... of course it is not always desired, but there's nothing that says they can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you write a `Sub` you can write a `Function`, just substitute the words at the beginning and at the end of your code.

Now, about how to return the values, obviously it will be an array, so you'll need to declare the array, set its size, fill its cells and return it. This can be done like this:

```
Function  yourFunction() as String()
    ' You already have an array named "titles" which stores the values you want 
    ' to return. Fill it exactly as you do in your original code.
    yourFunction = titles ' This is the way to return the array.
End Function
```

If you want to use this function in a worksheet (as a formula), remember that this is an array-function, so you'll need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shitf</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after you enter the function in the cell instead of just `[Enter]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have worked out the lines below but don't quite work so I will follow what you say above.

     Function GetTitles(shtName As String)
     Dim x As Long, y As Long
    
     With Worksheets(shtName)
        For x = 1 To .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If .Cells(4, x) <> "" Then
                y = y + 1
                .Cells(20, y) = .Cells(4, x)
        End If
        Next
     End With
    
     End Function

Answer (score 2):

You need to make an array function for this. So your function will take in inputs through a range

```
Function ReturnArray(Input as Range) as Variant
    ' Do stuff with the Input range
    Dim Output(m,n) as Variant

    'Loop through m,n to fill in the output values as you would in a range
    ReturnArray = Output
End Function
```

And when you put in the function in excel, type it in the cell after highlighting where you want the output and press `Ctrl-Shift-Return`